# Cannot connect on local server with pgadmin3 - No Error Popup

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm facing some troubles with my pgadmin.

To manage manage my postgreSQL, I've been installing postgreSQL through pgAdmin3 on my macBook (MacOS 10.11), because I used to have some conflict issues when I installed with homebrew. 
I have 2 types of servers I'm connecting: 1 on my laptop, and 1 in a remote server.

Don't know why, but after restarting my computer, I'm not able to connect to my local server anymore.

Here is the issue:

I try to connect to the localhost server, it asks for my password, then nothing. Not even an Error popup. But if I connect to remote server, no trouble.

On the footer of pgAdmin, I can read "Connecting to Database... Failed".
When I open the logs, here is what I got:

```
INFO   : Attempting to create a connection object...
STATUS : Connecting to database...
INFO   : Opening connection with connection string: host='localhost' dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password='XXXXXX' port=5432 sslcompression=0 application_name='pgAdmin III - Browser'
STATUS : Connecting to database... (0.06 secs)
```

I can even type a wrong password, just got nothing appearing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does postgres run after you rebooted the machine? ... or is this what you checked and meant with "connect to remote server, no trouble"?

Comment: I've been trying to reboot my machine again, but still cannot connect to my local servers. Got the problem only with my local servers. So far connection to remote ones works totally fine.

Comment: Ah, so you have two kinds of machines. What you reboot are "local" and those may not have postgres database running anymore. The "remote" ones are completely different? I read the question, as if database runs on remote server and you compare logging into remote server and connecting to database(?) with trying to connect to the same remot machines database but via local machine. Maybe you could update the question as others willing to help might encounter similar problems? That would be great.

Comment: So far I have my own computer where I've installed pgAdmin3 to manage my databases. So far I have my DB installed on my computer (local) and on our server (remote).
For the local one, I've installed it with the default localhost of pgAdmin and it's this one I cannot connect.
I've been trying to check with command line, but I havent found how to fix it since i havent installed on my computer (MacOS) by homebrew or yum, but only with pgAdmin3.